# How to write a method with an unknown type of return value in abstract class in C++?

Tags: c++, class, inheritance

For example, I now have two `struct`s.

```
struct Point_2d {
    int x, y;
};

struct Point_3d {
    int x, y, z;
};
```

And thus I've made two `class`es.

```
class Graph_2d {
public:
    Point_2d getFirstPoint(int a);
};

class Graph_3d {
public:
    Point_3d getFirstPoint(int a);
};
```

And now I want these two classes to be inherited from a abstract class, like so:

```
class Graph {
public:
    virtual ??? getFirstPoint(int a); // just define interface
};

class Graph_2d: public Graph {
public:
    Point_2d getFirstPoint(int a) {
         // implementation here
    }
};

// Graph_3d the same
```

wonder what to place in `???`, I've tried use `template <typename T> virtual T getFirstPoint();` but that didn't work.

I may don't want to use template class like `template <typename T> class Graph;`, but template method is acceptable. And `Point_2d` and `Point_3d` must be `struct` but not `class`.

Is there a way to correct it literally(grammarly) or do I must refactorizing?

Any reply is fervently anticipated. (Sorry for my poor English, I'm not a native English speaker but I'm trying to explain everything I need clearly.)

Comment: polymorphism and different return types don't go well together. I suggest to reconsider why you use virtual methods in the first place and how calling code should look like

Comment: It sounds like what should be templated is not the graphs themselves, but the functions that operate on the graphs. e.g. `template<typename T> Path<typename T::point_type> a_star(const T& graph, typename T::point_type from, typename T::point_type to);`. Then the methods don't even need to be virtual at all.

Comment: Please note that `struct` and `class` in C++ are essentially the same thing, but with different default access: `public` for `struct` and `private` for `class`.

Comment: The very fact that you have such a problem is a red flag for the design you've chosen. How would you *use* `Graph` polymorphically if you don't know the return type at the compile-time? Suppose you could write `auto` for `???`. What then?

Comment: This is a clear example of the [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  Consider asking "What is a good design choice?" instead of "How can I make polymorphism the good design choice?"

Comment: `virtual std::variant<Point_2d, Point_3d> getFirstPoint(int a);` will do what you want.  But Drew's comment should be taken to heart, since this is a bad design choice.  [`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant).

Answer (score 0):

You should absolutely take to heart everything said in the comments, the biggest question you need to answer for yourself here is exactly why you're trying to do things this way, and if it's really the right approach. BUT in the spirit of just giving you an answer to the question you asked, the piece you're missing is that if you're going to use abstraction on the getter, you need an abstract data type.

You can do something like this with pretty much zero overhead:

```
struct Point {
    int x, y;
};

typedef Point Point_2d;

struct Point_3d : public Point {
    int z;
};

class Graph {
public:
    virtual Point *getFirstPoint(int a);
};

class Graph_3d: public Graph {
public:
    Point *getFirstPoint(int a) override {
         return &points_[0];
    }
    Point_3d points_[20];
};
```

Of course this says nothing about exactly how you plan to use this. Any caller of `getFirstPoint()` will need to know exactly what type is being returned in order to up or downcast it, but I believe it satisfies your requirement as written.

Comment: If the caller knows which derived class they are working with, they can just cast the pointer/reference of the graph itself, and polymorphism is not needed anymore. This seems pointless to me.

Comment: I agree it’s a little silly. But we also have no idea how this person might use the information beyond the specific question asked so I’m happy to give them the benefit of the doubt.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should reconsider your design. Thinks about something like `std::variant<Point_2d, Point_3d> getFirstPoint(int a)` check out [std::variant](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant)

I'm just posting this code in case you REALLY want to do things this way.

```
#include <iostream>

struct point2d {
    int x, y;
};

struct point3d {
    int x, y, z;
};

template <typename T>
class GraphCommon{
public:
    void commonMethod() {std::cout << "Common methonds goes in this class\n";}
    virtual T getPoint(int a){}
};

template <typename T>
class Graph : public GraphCommon<T> {
public:
    virtual void notPureVirtual() {std::cout << "virtual functions goes here\n";}
    T getPoint() {std::cout << "base class\n";}
};

template<>
class Graph<point2d> : public GraphCommon<point2d> {
public:
    point2d getPoint(int a) override {std::cout << "2D pint is returned\n";}
};

template<>
class Graph<point3d> : public GraphCommon<point3d> {
public:
    point3d getPoint(int a) override {std::cout << "3D point is returned\n";}
};

int main() {

    Graph<point2d> p1;
    Graph<point3d> p2;
    p1.getPoint(1);
    p1.commonMethod();
    p2.getPoint(1);
    p2.commonMethod();
    p1.notPureVirtual() //Error, notPureVirtual() is not specialized for Graph<point2d>

    Graph<float> f;
    f.getPoint();
    f.notPureVirtual(); //But it works for Grapth<T>
    return 0;
}
```

The class `GraphCommon` is for the common functions between the specialized classes, without it you will have to redefine all the functions for each specialization even if you will not change them.